# Logo to appear in fixed footer div when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, css

//I have tried to find threads with similar specifics but has not found any. I apologize on beforehand if this has been discused before. In that case please give me a link or similar.//

The code I found is not exactly what I want but with sone changes it might could give what I want? Page contain of three main DIVs that is  header (where logo is placed), main body div, and the footer div (where I want logo to fade in and out regards to the scrolling described below. The header div has the height of 60 px.

WHAT NEEDED

-In head there will be a logo img or logo text. logo will be fixed at top all the time and do not need to fade out and be unvisible. Just visible all the time. 
- when logo in top disappears because of normal scrolling down the page. I want a logo placed in the footer div to fade in and appear and be visible as long as the top logo not are visible. If scrolling up to the top again the footer logo fade out and disappear.

Page I want this effect on can be found in this  [link](http://proffinfo.com), this so you easier can imagine what I want. I assume that some elements in this code found  in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857164/how-to-make-logo-appear-in-fixed-menu-when-scrolling-down-page) might be of use. Please advice me on what needs to be changed to make it work regards what I want to achieve. My attempts earlier has not been succesfull

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Stackoverflow is not a free coding service.  You can provide what you have tried and community will assist you in fixing your code.

Comment: I understand what the problem is - see answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to control the visibility of the logo in the footer based on the visibility of the logo in the header.

You can achieve this very easily with [headroom.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/)

Code sample:

```js
var header = document.querySelector("header");

var options = {
  offset:100,
  onUnpin: function () {
    $('footer .logo').fadeIn();
  },
  
  onTop: function() {
     $('footer .logo').fadeOut();
  }
};

var headroom  = new Headroom(header, options);
headroom.init();
```

```css
header,
footer {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#ddd;
  text-align:center;
  }

footer {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  }

footer .logo {
  display:none;
}

main img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/headroom.js@0.9.3/dist/headroom.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="logo">L O G O </h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Brigantine-Falado-von-Rhodos-1999-07.jpg">
  </main>
  <footer>
    <h1 class="logo">L O G O</h1>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some quick jQuery that will move the logo depending on where you've scrolled. Just add a class `.hasLogo` to `#myTopnav` and watch/manipulate that.

```js
var $tn = $('#myTopnav'),
    $header = $tn.find('li').eq(1),
    $logo = $header.find('img'),
    $footer = $('#FooterDiv'),
    tnTop = $tn.offset().top,
    tnHeight = $tn.outerHeight(),
    tnBot = tnTop + tnHeight;
    
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scrollTop > tnBot) {
    if (! $footer.hasClass('hasLogo')) {
      $logo.appendTo($footer);
      $footer.addClass('hasLogo');
      $tn.removeClass('hasLogo');
    }
  } else if (! $tn.hasClass('hasLogo')) {
    $logo.appendTo($header);
    $tn.addClass('hasLogo');
    $footer.removeClass('hasLogo');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html style="height:100%">
  <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=euc-kr">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://proffinfo.com/stylesheet/proffinfo.css">
  
 <style>
 



  body {
    margin:0;
    background-image: url("proffinfo/img/fishing2.jpg");
    background-color: grey;
    } 



body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  word-wrap: break-word; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1em;
  font-weight: 700; }

p {
  line-height: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 300; }

body {
  font-size: 1.2em; }

@media screen and (min-width: 680px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.4em; } }
@media screen and (min-width: 1224px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.6em; } }
@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.8em; } }
h1 {
  font-size: 2em; }

h2 {
  font-size: 1.8em; }

h3 {
  font-size: 1.6em; }

h4 {
  font-size: 1.4em; }

h5 {
  font-size: 1.2em; }

p {
  font-size: 1.2em; }

h6 {
  font-size: 1em; 

}




body {margin:0;}
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  
  border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-color: grey;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: grey;
  
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 23px;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #282828;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}




div properties mainbody
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    
}
.container div {
    height: ';
}

.column-left {
    width: 10%;
    left: 0;
    background: ;
    position: absolute;
}
.main-body {
    width: 78%;
    background: ;
    margin-left: 11%;
    margin-right: 11%;
    position: absolute;
}
.column-right {
    width: 10%;
    height: 70%;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: ;
}



 
 #FooterDiv {
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
 
}



 </style>   
        
<script>
//topmenu
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>


  </head>
  <body style="height:70%">

<div id="full" style="z-index: 1; left: 0px; top: 50px; width: 530px; 
height: 100%; width: 100%;">

<div id="header" style="z-index:; 
height: 60px; width: 100%; background-color:; visibility: visible; ">

<font color="grey"><h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;ProffInfo</h1></font>

<ul class="topnav hasLogo" id="myTopnav">
  <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home"><img height="21" width="21" align="middle" src="http://shababsa7.net/images/PageImage-515435-3918738-home_icon.png"></a></li>
  
  <li><a href="http://proffinfo.com/mainpage/omoss.php" size="10">Om oss</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://proffinfo.com/mainpage/tjenester.php">V&aring;re tjenester</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://proffinfo.com/forum">Forum</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://proffinfo.com/mainpage/tjenester.php">Kontakt</a></li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">��</a>
  </li>
</ul>

</div>
<br><br><br>







<div style='position:absolute; top:200; left:0; width:100%; 
 height:1000px; background-color:;' >



<div class="container">
   
   <div class="main-body">
 <br>  
<b>     
<h1>body contents go</h1></b> <br>
here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here body contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go herebody contents go here
  
   </div>
</div> 


<div class="column-left">column-left</div>
<div class="column-right">Column-right</div>
</div>
    
  
    
</div>
<div id="FooterDiv" style='position:fixed; bottom:0; left:0; width:100%;  background-color:#252525; border-top: 1px solid grey; border-bottom: 1px solid grey;'>
   <font size"5" color="grey">
            <center>&#169 ProffInfo.com<br>Din nettleverand&oslash;r</a></center>

    
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```